# Looking to simplify my code

Tags: vba, simplify

The code below is very repetitive and it looks like the words I need to replace can be subbed into the three lines of code one by one, I'm just not sure how to do it.

If anyone is wondering it's just a bit of code to find and replace common errors. This is in Visual Basic. Thanks!

```
Cells.Replace What:=" uk ", Replacement:=" UK ", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Cells.Replace What:=" info ", Replacement:=" information ", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Cells.Replace What:="havant", Replacement:="haven't", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Cells.Replace What:="everytime", Replacement:="every time", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Cells.Replace What:="wouldnt", Replacement:="wouldn't", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Cells.Replace What:="couldnt", Replacement:="couldn't", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Cells.Replace What:="shouldnt", Replacement:="shouldn't", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Cells.Replace What:="scottish", Replacement:="Scottish", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Cells.Replace What:="havnt", Replacement:="haven't", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Cells.Replace What:="must of", Replacement:="must have", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Cells.Replace What:="on line", Replacement:="online", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Cells.Replace What:="help full", Replacement:="helpful", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Cells.Replace What:="xmas", Replacement:="Christmas", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Cells.Replace What:="christmas", Replacement:="Christmas", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Cells.Replace What:=" allot ", Replacement:=" a lot", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Cells.Replace What:="vip", Replacement:="VIP", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Cells.Replace What:="  ", Replacement:=" ", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Cells.Replace What:="on line", Replacement:="online", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Cells.Replace What:=" usa ", Replacement:=" USA ", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Cells.Replace What:=" wales ", Replacement:=" Wales ", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Cells.Replace What:=" dif ", Replacement:=" did ", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Cells.Replace What:=" saif ", Replacement:=" said ", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
```

Answer (score 3):

You could create a multidimensional array (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d2de1t93(v=vs.90).aspx) that contains the original and new values

Then loop through the array calling your Cells.Replace once within the loop (0 = original, 1 = replacement)

```
Dim newArray(5,1) as string
newarray(0,0) = "info"
newArray(0,1) = "information"

For x = 0 to 5
Cells.Replace What:=newArray(x,0), Replacement:=newArray(x,1), LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False

Next
```

Comment: That's great, thanks, just gonna ask another amateur question, how do I add another replacement to that?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean? Do you mean add more to the array (newArray)?

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to tick my answer! :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify all the options, then it remembers your last time. So `SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False`
is redunant after the first time you specify. Properties, like Methods, are Function Calls, which are slowish. Each line makes 4 extra functions calls, none needed after the first line.